# POST request path for upload file to AlfrescoCloud storage

Tags: alfresco

please show example of POST request path for upload file to AlfrescoCloud storage.

I have been trying to upload using example from tutorial
http://ecmarchitect.com/images/articles/cmis/cmis-article.pdf
but getting bad XML format error response.

can any one, please bring clean example of Atom Entry XML package.

Comment: Why are you not just using one of the many CMIS libraries that does it all for you?

Comment: I'm on Delphi platform, please let me know if there are any CMIS libraries for Delphi? When I'm done my part can be used as CMIS library for Alfresco, I hope.

Comment: No idea, but if you ask on the Apache Chemisty list it's possible someone there will do. If not, do you have any delphi bindings for other languages like C or Java? If so, you could just call out to one of the CMIS libraries in those